# Instaling pyodbc on linux

Tags: pyodbc

On RHEL trying to install pyodbc getting below error:

> InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-q948yR/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Fdkc1f-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-q948yR/pyodbc

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a pre-requisite package to built `pyodbc`. On RHEL:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
```

If you're connecting to SQL Server, don't forget FreeTDS:

```
sudo yum install freetds-devel
```

Good luck!